# Apply selectively a single filter to MockMvc from Spring Security when it is not autowirable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is defined with `http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());`

I want to do an integration test that only activates CSRF filtering but i got a problem:

- CSRFTokenRepository is not exposed in the context
- CSRFilter does not seem to be exposed in the context as a bean by Spring

I would like to test in the following fashion:

```
   this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(super.webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurity(CSRFFilter.class)) //This is just a showcase of that I pretend
            .alwaysDo(print())
            .build();
```

How can I selectively apply a single filter like CSRFFilter to my integration test instead of the generic SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Please note that this answer is accompanied by a complete and working sample.*

This kind of questions are interesting. Because it goes as follows

1. There is a problem identified, that problem is not disclosed in the Stack Overflow question
2. There is a proposed solution to the problem
3. The proposed solution becomes the question, but we don't know that it is the best solution

So I'm not sure that you should be modifying the filter chain on your application in your test. The end result is that you are not testing your application, but you are testing your modified application that will never be in production.

For the benefit of the doubt to whereas the posed question is the best solution, this is possible. Here is how I did it

I've created a [custom filter](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/c5dd4e80980c61975ed9423cbb70297d0ea1a071/samples/custom-rest-authentication/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/CustomizeFilterChainTests.java?ts=4#L97-L105) that returns 500 error before any other filter gets executed .

```
static class FiveHundredFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus(500);
        response.getWriter().write("TEST FILTER CHAIN");
    }
}
```

Then I created a [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/c5dd4e80980c61975ed9423cbb70297d0ea1a071/samples/custom-rest-authentication/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/CustomizeFilterChainTests.java?ts=4#L84-L95) that adds this filter to all my filter chains. You can select which chains to add it to here.

```
static class SecurityFilterChainPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if ("springSecurityFilterChain".equals(beanName)) {
            FilterChainProxy fcp = (FilterChainProxy) bean;
            for (SecurityFilterChain fc : fcp.getFilterChains()) {
                fc.getFilters().add(0, new FiveHundredFilter());
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

and finally I expose the [`SecurityFilterChainPostProcessor`](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/c5dd4e80980c61975ed9423cbb70297d0ea1a071/samples/custom-rest-authentication/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/CustomizeFilterChainTests.java?ts=4#L62-L70) as a bean in my application context

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org/springframework/security/community/samples")
public static class SpringBootApplicationTestConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChainPostProcessor securityFilterChainPostProcessor() {
        return new SecurityFilterChainPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

I believe this should solve your dilemma.